# compositeData of custom control is undefined in beforeRenderResponse event

Tags: xpages

When passing data to a custom control, I have always used the compositeData object to access this data from inside the control. This is working fine, except for the beforeRenderResponse event of the custom control. Take this code as an example:

```
<xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("lbl0").setValue(typeof(compositeData));}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("lbl1").setValue(typeof(compositeData));}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
<xp:label value="" id="lbl0"/>
<xp:label value="" id="lbl1"/>
```

In the afterPageLoad event, the typeof of the compositeData is "com.ibm.xsp.binding.PropertyMap". Yet in the beforeRenderResponse event, the same typeof returns "undefined".

How can I access the compositeData in the beforeRenderResponse event?

Comment: Try calculating the beforeRenderResponse on "page load" so using $ instead of # (<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[${javascript:getComponent("lbl1").setValue(typeof(compositeData));}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>)

Comment: When I calculate the event on page load, I get an error: "getComponent() is null". Anyway, computing only on page load is not really an option in my case because I want to partially refresh the custom control when its parameters change.

Comment: Based on my observation, this also happens not only for compositeData but also for currentDocument and other data sources defined in an xpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *beforePageLoad* or *afterPageLoad* create a SSJS variable with a reference to the *compositeData*:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:
      var hlp=compositeData;
   }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

This allows you to access the PropertyMap during the Rendering Phase. If you have a property *test* you can then acces it this way:

```
<xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:
      print( hlp.test );
   }]]>
</xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
```

**EDIT:**
This works only if the page is opened (pageLoad). If you refresh the page, this won't work. If it has to run with partial refreshs, you have to do this:

First, you have to add an ID to your custom control:

```
<xc:ccWithId test="I am your property" id="ccWithId" />
```

This allows you to access the custom control as a regular component with *getComponent()*. Now you can access the propertyMap of the component in the custom control's event which holds the variable you want:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:
      var cmp:com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite = getComponent("ccWithId");
      print("Value of 'test' -> " + cmp.getPropertyMap().getString("test") )
   }]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

**EDIT by xpages-noob**: The example from above works fine for static custom control properties. However, in case a property is computed, the various get functions of the property map return a value binding object instead of the value itself. Hence, one can use the following function as a workaround:

```
 var thisData:com.ibm.xsp.binding.PropertyMap=getComponent("ccWithId").getPropertyMap();
function getPara(key) {
    var x=thisData.get(key);
    if (@Ends(typeof(x),"ValueBinding")) return x.getValue(facesContext);
    else return x
}
```

If you want to, for example, get the property "test", call getPara("test"). The returned value should be equal to compositeData.test.

Comment: I have tried that before, but this trick only works the first time the page loads. When I partially refresh the custom control, the typeof of the helper variable (hlp) is again undefined, probably because "var hlp=compositeData;" is not executed during the refresh and hlp no longer exists.

Comment: Didn't noticed the 'partial refresh' part of your question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution. Even though I don't get why the compositeData is not available in the beforeRenderResponse event, it works fine now. I hope you don't mind that I added a few lines to your answer describing the case where the custom control's properties are not static.

Comment: The compositeData is not available because it is "running" in another context (See http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1099 ). Thanks for your idea with the dynamic properties. But currently there seems to be a problem with the review of your edit... I am trying to figure out why.